# The deriviation of liu estimator

Tags: regression

I want to know the steps to find the liu estimator which is combine the ridge regression and stein estimate

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Can you expand your question to explain what you have already figured out and what you are struggling with. Also, if this is homework, you should use the homework tag.

Comment: I study the r-d class estimator which is combines the liu estimator and the PCR estimator so i need to know the steps of liu estimator

Comment: What software or programming language would you prefer?

Comment: I prefer R language